# Convert to a complete BST function

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I need to save data in the bst to a sorted array, then, the `ConvertToCompleteBST` function clears current tree and uses the array to re-insert the values recursively by inserting the middle value in each call.

```
InsertRecursively(data_array,size);
```

For example, if the array was 
[5 7 10 12 16 18 30]

then `InsertRecursively([5 7 10 12 16 18 30],7)` is called first,

the middle is **12** so 12 is the first one is inserted into the tree. Then in the recursive call , it will do the same but for

```
InsertRecursively([5 7 10],3)
InsertRecursively([16 18 30],3)
```

Then, `InsertRecursively([5 7 10],3)` will lead to inserting the node **7** and two other recursive calls

`InsertRecursively([5],1)`  >> lead to inserting node 5

`InsertRecursively([10],1)` >> lead to inserting node 10

When size is 1, it will stop the recursive call.

I have no idea how to implement the insertRecursively function

Comment: What does your bst data structure look like?

Comment: Is it the recursive part or the terminal part you're having trouble with?

Comment: I'm having trouble with the recursive part